# ¿Cómo leer correctamente los datos de un Json en Java?

Tags: java, json, jsonobject, jsonarray

estoy tratando de leer un archivo json en java utilizando json-simple 1.1.1 en vscode, el archivo json que estoy utilizando es el siguiente:

```
{   
"PlatoFuerte":[{
    "nombre" : "Hamburguesa",
    "precio" : "1500" ,
    "duracion" : "5",
    "tamaño" : "entero"
  },

  { "nombre" : "ArrozConCamarones",
    "precio" : "3000" ,
    "duracion" : "5",
    "tamaño" : "entero"
  },

  { "nombre" : "ArrozConPollo",
    "precio" : "2500" ,
    "duracion" : "5",
    "tamaño" : "entero"
  },

  { "nombre" : "FileteDePescado",
    "precio" : "2700" ,
    "duracion" : "5",
    "tamaño" : "medio"
    }
]
}
```

Y el código que estoy utilizando actualmente para la lectura del archivo json es el siguiente:

```java
import java.io.FileReader;

import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        FileReader reader = new FileReader("C:\\Users\\kevin\\Desktop\\LeerMenu\\Menu.json");
        Object obj = parser.parse(reader);
        JSONObject pJsonObj = (JSONObject)obj;
        JSONArray array = (JSONArray)pJsonObj.get("PlatoFuerte");
        
        for(int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++){
            JSONObject PlatoFuerte = (JSONObject)array.get(i);
            
            String nombrePlato = (String) PlatoFuerte.get("nombre");
            String precioPlato = (String) PlatoFuerte.get("precio");
            String duracionPlato = (String) PlatoFuerte.get("duracion");
            String tamanoPlato = (String) PlatoFuerte.get("tamaño"); 
            
            System.out.println( "\nLos Platos fuertes son: ");
            System.out.println( "Nombre del plato: " + nombrePlato);
            System.out.println( "Precio: " + precioPlato);
            System.out.println( "Duracion: " + duracionPlato);
            System.out.println( "Tamaño: " + tamanoPlato); 
        }
    }
}
```

Y utilizando el código anterior obtengo este error:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.Long cannot be cast to class java.lang.String (java.lang.Long and java.lang.String are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
at App.main(App.java:29)

Comment: El mensaje de error te está diciendo que estás intentando leer un `Long`  como un `String`. ¿Cuál es la línea 29 de la clase `App`?

Comment: Podría asumir que estas tratando de parsear el precio como String cuando es un Long. Podrías intentar parsearlo con `String.valueOf(PlatoFuerte.get("precio"))`

Comment: @LuisA parece que el parser que está usando convierte ciertos datos al tipo `Long`, pues `Long` no existe en JSON ... si deben ser `Long` quizá sea mejor declarar la variable como `Long` definitivamente: `Long precioPlato = PlatoFuerte.get("precio");`

Comment: Claro, tienes razón @A.Cedano. Lo mejor sería declararlo Long. Yo solo lo mencione como una opción más ya que no conozco la linea 29 de su app. Por eso asumí

Comment: La versión que usas de la llibrería es la oficial? https://search.maven.org/search?q=json-simple

Comment: La línea 29 de mi código es esta: String precioPlato = (String) PlatoFuerte.get("precio");

Comment: @RuslanLópez sí, estoy utilizando la librería oficial

Comment: @A.Cedano, Gracias, sí funcionó declarar la variable como Long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La excepción:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class
> java.lang.Long cannot be cast to class java.lang.String

Te dice claramente que estás intentando convertir un dato de tipo `Long`  a `String`.

Si la librería que estás usando te convierte los valores numéricos del JSON a `Long`, no conviene hacer de nuevo un casting a String. Puedes declararlo como `Long` directamente haciendo esto:

```
Long precioPlato = PlatoFuerte.get("precio");
```

O, si quieres trabajar con primitivos:

```
long precioPlato = (Long) PlatoFuerte.get("precio");
```